# Magento: Custom module not working on magento 1.3.2.3

Tags: magento

I have designed a custom magento extension. It has custom menus on magento admin panel. I have tested it on magento 1.5. But when I tested it on magento 1.3.2.3 it didn't show any menu. I have checked module status from System->Configraion->Advanced and it is enabled there. What could be the possible problems here??? Why my module is not working on magento1.3.2.3??

Please help.

Comment: Did you try logging out and logging back in? ACL permissions (which sohw items in the menu) when you log in, so try logging out and logging back in.

Comment: I've tried it, but no luck :(

Comment: If you break your XML somehow, do you see an XML parse error?

Comment: I didn't see any XML parse error.

Answer (score 2):

1. Clean cache.
2. Try to remove ACL(if any) from config.xml.
3. As already suggested: Log out and Log in.
4. Check logs in (mage root)/var/logs/ system.log and exception.log
5. Check config.xml structure of any default module. For example, check

   (mage root)/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/etc/config.xml

I suppose there should be something useful for you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need your Helper->Data.php in place and also have the entry for the helper in your config.xml, sth like:

```
 <global>
     <helpers>
        <Mymodule>
            <class>Myspace_Mymodule_Helper</class>
        </Mymodule>
    </helpers>
</global>
```